# Similarity measures for WordNet in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I would like to be able to check if two words are similar (using the path similarity) in WordNet with Prolog.

I found on the internet this [article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjZ1OPq_8r4AhWsQPEDHff6DXYQFnoECBkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.atlantis-press.com%2Farticle%2F125914883.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3l-dacpcMCl9-MER-4jUYC)  doing exactly what I want.

I'll paste here the steps needed to let this work:

1. Download WordNet 3.0 Prolog version from
   http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/3.0/WNprolog-3.0.tar.gz
   and unzip it in a directory of your choice. For example:
   c:\wn_prologDB
2. Set the environment variable WNDB to this newly created directory.
   For example, use either the system dialog box in Control Panel
   (Environment Variables), or write in a Command Prompt (cmd.exe):
   set WNDB=c:\wn_prologDB
3. Download the modules of WN_CONNECT from
   https://dectau.uclm.es/bousi-prolog/applications and unzip
   it in a directory of your choice. For example:
   c:\wn
4. Add to the PATH environment variable the directory where this tool
   is located (similar to step 2 above):
   set PATH=c:\wn;%PATH%
5. Open a terminal and execute the shell script:
   wn.sh

I followed those steps, and run wn.bat (since I'm using windows).

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the `wn_word_info` predicate is working, while I cannot understand why `wn_path` is not working.

Here is the signature:

```
wn_path(+Word1, +Word2, -Degree)
```

Any tips on how I could get it to work? Or any solution to calculate path similarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature was a bit different:

```
wn_path(+Word1:SS_type1:W1_Sense_num, +Word2:SS_type2:W2_Sense_num, -Degree)
```

So this actually works:

```
wn_path(cat:A:B, dog:C:D, E).
```

Here I'm specifying only the word and the other parameters are variables, but one can specify all three the parameters.

I paste here some of the docs I found in the WN_CONNECT folder:

> ** wn_path(+Word1:SS_type1:W1_Sense_num, +Word2:SS_type2:W2_Sense_num, -Degree):
> This predicate implements the PATH similarity measure.
> Takes two concepts (terms -- Word:SS_type:Sense_num) and returns the degree of similarity between them. Note that we do not explicitly require information about the synset type and sense number of a word (that can be variables).